# Go Tour #11 - Why this slice changes its capacity?

Tags: go

In this slide of [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/11), there is this snippet:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    s := []int{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13}
    printSlice(s)

    // Slice the slice to give it zero length.
    s = s[:0]
    printSlice(s)

    // Extend its length.
    s = s[:4]
    printSlice(s)

    // Drop its first two values.
    s = s[2:]
    printSlice(s)
}

func printSlice(s []int) {
    fmt.Printf("len=%d cap=%d %v\n", len(s), cap(s), s)
}
```

and the result:

```
len=6 cap=6 [2 3 5 7 11 13]
len=0 cap=6 []
len=4 cap=6 [2 3 5 7]
len=2 cap=4 [5 7]
```

My confusion is about the `cap=4` in the last line - I thought it should remain 6.

What is the cause of the capacity changing from 6 to 4 in the last line?

Also, why only the last line changes its capacity but the others don't ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Remember that slice holds data in an array. By dropping first two elements we moved the beginning of the slice to the right and now there are fewer slots between the start of the slice inside the array and the end of the array.

Droping elements at the end of the slice has no effect on capacity as the distance between start of the slice inside the array and the end of the backing array does not change.

Neither of the operations modify the backing array, they just modify the slice data.

See https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals the observed behaviour is explained in section **Slice internals**

By printing the slice header you can see the changes happening

```
func printSlice(s []int) {
    sh := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&s))
    fmt.Printf("header=%+v len=%d cap=%d %v\n", sh, len(s), cap(s), s)
}
```

In the last call, the data pointer is moved ahead.

```
header=&{Data:272990208 Len:6 Cap:6} len=6 cap=6 [2 3 5 7 11 13]
header=&{Data:272990208 Len:0 Cap:6} len=0 cap=6 []
header=&{Data:272990208 Len:4 Cap:6} len=4 cap=6 [2 3 5 7]
header=&{Data:272990216 Len:2 Cap:4} len=2 cap=4 [5 7]
```

Comment: I believe the question is about why has the droping of two last elements not the same effect.

Comment: Thanks. So, does that mean that dropping the last elements and the first elements are very different operations - dropping the last elems really just creates a "view" but dropping the first elems actually modifies the underlying array and get us a view based on it?

Comment: @akai Indeed, they are quite different.

Comment: I've checked your edit and will read the blog post, thanks again.

Comment: @GrzegorzŻur - thanks, glad you added the code showing the data pointer stuff I was trying to explain in the answer below. It all makes better sense now.

Comment: Worth noting, all slice operations are just "views", as you put it.  Dropping the first element doesn't modify the underlying array any more than dropping the last element does.  What it _does_ do it advance the "start" pointer in the slice header.  The "length" and "capacity" values for a slice are referenced from that "start" pointer (which is what `Data` in the above code is).  If you have a slice with length 6, and you advance the start pointer 2 elements, the end is now only 4 from the start, so the capacity gets reduced to 4.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47817849/behaviour-of-pointer-in-slice/47819242#47819242) for more details about how slice headers function.

Comment: I'm back to Golang finally, and I now think that saying "dropping the last and the first are very different" wasn't very appropriate. `cap` really just contains the distance from [the pointer of the first elem of the slice] to [the end of its underlying array], that's it. I feel @Kaedys's statement was more accurate.

Answer (score 5):

Basically a slice has 3 elements :

1. ***pointer to data***
2. length
3. capacity.

The pointer to data is a reference to an underlying array (fixed size, contiguous allocation).

One can take any subset of this slice to form another slice (all that changes is the pointer to data, start of the slice.).

When one selects a subset 0 to m (m > 0) elements from the left of a slice sized N (m < N), then one has items 0 to m in the new slice and at the same time the entire underlying array capacity available (as the ***pointer to data*** still points to location 0). So one can expand it till N without any change in capacity.

However if one slices m (m > 0) to k (k < N), then the ***pointer to start of data is now pointing to location of m*** and the new length is from m to k - but now we only have capacity m to N in the new slice. We have lost access of elements 0 to m in the new slice forever. Once we understand that it's just a pointer manipulation similar to other languages/architectures, it's fairly simple. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

This [go blog](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals) clarifies this point by explaining that the array consists of actual values and the slice in contrast contains a pointer to the array, more specifically that pointer points to an element of the array: "The capacity is the number of elements in the underlying array (***beginning at the element referred to by the slice pointer***)"